# Call a Non Static Member Method from Another Method

Tags: c++, class, methods, static-methods

Is there a way to call a non static class member method from another method that is contained within the main class in c++? If so, what would the code look like?

Problem is, I can't declare this specfic method as static, because it uses other methods within the same class that then don't work if I make the one static.

I'm trying to use:

```
MyClass::myClassMethod();
```

from a method within the main class, but it gives me the error: a non static member reference must be relative to a specific object.

To clarify, myClassMethod() uses other methods within MyClass like:

```
void myClassMethod() {
    ...
    anotherClassMethod();
}
```

so if I were to make myClassMethod static it would interfere with calling anotherClassMethod().

Comment: After reading the question and comments in the already-posted answers, it would still be useful to have some more information about what you're trying to do.  Is `myClassMethod` itself static? Where is it being called from? Can you change the arguments to the method? What is the goal of the problem you've been assigned?

Comment: Seems like you really need to have a think about what behaviour you might want here. The key difference with static and no-static methods is that the latter needs to access either class data, or perhaps make virtual calls which internally do much the same. If `myClassMethod` calls `anotherClassMethod` which is non-static, do either need to do this? If not, make them static. If so, then what do you expect to happen when the method attempts to access the data?

Answer (score 8):

**What is the deal with calling non-static member function from a `static` member function?**

Every non static member function is passed an `this` pointer implicitly in addition to the parameters you pass, the pointer passed is then dereferenced to refer class object members However `static` functions are not passed with the implicit `this`pointer and hence one cannot call any non static member function inside a static member function because there is no `this` to do so.

**What is the solution, If you want to do it anyways?**

You will need some mechanism to get the pointer to the object inside the static method and then you can call the member function using that pointer.
**How to do that?**
You will have to store the pointer to class object globally, or pass it as an instance in one of the function arguments to the static method.

However, both of above are workarounds, the important thing to note here is If you feel the need of calling a non static member function through a static member function then there is something wrong in your design.

---

On Second thoughts maybe I mis-read your Question before, Probably, Your question is:

**How to call a non-static member function of a class from `main`?**

You need a instance of the class to call non-static member functions.
So simply,

```
MyClass obj; 
obj.myClassMethod();
```

And calling any other member function from within `myClassMethod()` would simply be:

```
void myClassMethod()
{
   //...
   anyOtherMyClassNonStaticMemberFunction(); 
   //...
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm a newbie. How would I do this?

Comment: @aclark: Please Check the updated answer, I added some more detail.Does it make sense?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Problem is, the design is given by the instructor, so I have to work with it. Seems pretty convoluted to me too :-/

Answer (score 4):

A static method is one that doesn't run on any particular object.  It's a lot like a standalone function outside of a class, except that it's allowed to access private members in its class.

If you `anotherClassMethod()` is non-static, that means it has to be called on a specific object, an instance of the class.  Because it's called on an object, it can access data stored in that object (non-static member variables).  If `myClassMethod()` is static and you implement it as

```
void MyClass::myClassMethod() {
  anotherClassMethod();
}
```

That won't work because `anotherClassMethod()` expects to be called on a specific object, but `myClassMethod()` doesn't have one.  But if you know what object you want to call it on, you can do it as an ordinary method call on an object:

```
void MyClass::myClassMethod(MyClass &object) {
  object.anotherClassMethod();
}
```

The `object` doesn't have to be passed in as an argument; it could be a static member variable in the class, for example:

```
class MyClass {
private:
  static MyClass theInstance;

  // ...
};

void MyClass::myClassMethod() {
  theInstance.anotherClassMethod();
}
```

Ultimately, the question you need to ask yourself is:  why is `myClassMethod()` static, and why is `anotherClassMethod()` non-static?  Take a step back, think about what `myClassMethod()` is supposed to do.  Does it make sense to call it when you don't have an instance to work with?  If so, why does it need to call a method that expects to work with an instance?

Answer (score 3):

The only way to call a non static method of a class is through an instance of that class. So you would need something like this...

```
MyClass myClass;
myClass.myClassMethod();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that maybe you could use the singleton pattern, keep a instance of the class in global. like a utility class.